# Quality of AV Kit vs. Brightcove when playing preroll advertisements

Tags: iad, brightcove, avkit, preroll

I'm trying to decide which framework to go with. I understand that one of the main concerns in video prerolls is maintaining a smooth transition from the ad to the video content, and also video quality itself. How does the quality of Brightcove compare to that of AV Kit?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: A "quality" comparison doesn't make sense. The Brightcove SDK uses AVFoundation for playback, but adds a lot on top of that, such as a UI, integrations with Brightcove's video catalog, analytics and ad servers.

Comment: I'm talking about the the quality in terms of smooth transitions, smooth adaptive streaming, appropriate buffering, etc., not the quality of the API's.